# while installing cosmos gui "npm start" throws error

Tags: node.js, fiware-cosmos

[cosmos-gui@cosmos-instance cosmos-gui]$ npm start

> cosmos-gui@1.0.0-next start /home/cosmos-gui/fiware-cosmos/cosmos-gui
>   
> > node ./src/cosmos_gui.js

/home/cosmos-gui/fiware-cosmos/cosmos-
gui/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:110
 
     throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer 
bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see 
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.');
      ^

Error: Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and 
must be installed separately. Please see 
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

    at Function.get (/home/cosmos-gui/fiware-cosmos/cosmos-
gui/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:110:13)
 
   at Object. (/home/cosmos-gui/fiware-cosmos/cosmos-
gui/src/cosmos_gui.js:66:17)
  
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
  
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
 
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
  
  at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
  
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
  
  at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
  
  at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
  
  at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! cosmos-gui@1.0.0-next start: `node ./src/cosmos_gui.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the cosmos-gui@1.0.0-next start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/cosmos-gui/.npm/_logs/2019-02-13T09_22_21_224Z-debug.log

Any solution for this?

Comment: «Error: Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and
must be installed separately. Please see
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.» Did you already follow this steps? Which was the result?

Comment: yes i followed this guide did :npm install connect..but i am not getting what to do further?do i have to craete files using code?

Comment: `npm install` only installs what is already specified in *package.json*. The error message you posted is telling you that some middleware which was previously bunled within *express* package is no more included so you need to install it manually. That is: Find that package in npmjs.com (due to pick the right package name) and execute `npm install --save <package_name>`.